# Manipulate Excel table macro to another format. Remove duplicates and reformat

Tags: excel, vba, string, manipulate

I'm around 2 months in my VBA journey and I have encountered a problem which I can't find a solution to online. I'm having problems manipulating an Excel table to another format which has been created by another macro that I have programmed. I have a table with country and name of a figure on different rows, listed on a couple of rows. I want it to be dynamic since this table will be updated everyday

I have written below on how I want it to look. My idea is to code the country as a digit and then remove duplicats in the country region.

I have tried to create a loop and I'm thinking that I might have to create a range for each country.

```
Sub ManipulateTable()
Dim Country as String
Dim USA as Range
Dim EU as Range
Dim India as Range

Const StartRow As Byte = 7
Dim LastRow as Long
LastRow = Range("A" & StartRow.(End(xlDown).Row

For i StartRow to LastRow 
Country = Range("A" & i).Value

If Country = "USA" Then Range("C" & i).value = 1
If Country = "EU" Then Range("C" & i).value = 2
If Country = "India" Then Range("C" & i).value = 3
Next i
' This to remove duplicates from column a
Range("A7:A30").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1). Header:= xlYes
' I thinking that I need to create a loop here 
' But I dont know where to start
For i StartRow to LastRow
Countryindex =  Range("C").Value
If Countryindex = 1 Then put under USA
If Countryindex = 2 Then put under EU
```

My Table looks like this with separate columns

```
    "A" "B"
     Data
1    USA Sales
2    USA Employment Figures
3    USA Tax
4    EU Sales
5    EU Employment Figures
6    India Sales
7    India Expenses 
8    India Employment Figures
```

I want a table which looks like this

```
 "A" 
 Data
1    USA: (With some color)
2    Sales
3    Employment
4    Tax
5    EU: (With some color)  
6    Sales
7    Employment
8    India: (With some color)
9    Sales
10   Expenses
11   Employment
```

All help is highly appriciated.

```
Country Data Time

Country:
Data Time
```

Comment: If you remove duplicates, won't you just be left with rows 1, 4 and 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save a copy before you run this it will overwrite your data.

```
Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim iter As Long
    Dim diter As Long
    Dim countrydict As Object
    Dim country As String
    Dim data As String
    Dim key As Variant

    Set countrydict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With ActiveSheet
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

        For iter = 1 To lastrow
            country = Trim(.Cells(iter, 1).value)
            data = Trim(.Cells(iter, 2).value)
            If countrydict.Exists(country) Then
                If Not InStr(1, countrydict(country), data) > 0 Then ' Remove Dupes
                    countrydict(country) = countrydict(country) & "|" & data ' an array would work but we can instr a string
                End If
            Else
                countrydict.Add country, data
            End If
        Next
        iter = 1
        For Each key In countrydict
            .Cells(iter, 1).value = key & ":"
            .cells(iter, 1).font.bold = True
            .cells(iter, 1).font.colorindex = 30
            iter = iter + 1
            For diter = 0 To UBound(Split(countrydict(key), "|"))
                .Cells(iter, 1).value = Split(countrydict(key), "|")(diter)
                iter = iter + 1
            Next
        Next
        .Columns("B").Clear
    End With
```

Comment: One further quenstion. How would you add another format to the country rows. Let's say that I'd like to make every country row in bold font. Thanks

Comment: Added in bold and a red font color. if you want to change the cell color use: ```.cells(iter, 1).interior.colorindex```

Comment: Another questions, let's say that I have a third column with a variable like time, how would I add that one data cell. Let's say that the lines look like

Comment: Country Data Time

Comment: And I want it to be

Comment: Country and then Data Time under

Comment: I entered it in the post

Comment: You'll either need a second dictionary with the same setup: key-country, item-datetime.  You could create an array to hold two strings for each data type or you can write a simple class that just stores data to make a clearer data structure.